# Reporting Services: Strange Behaviour with hidden rows

Tags: reporting-services, business-intelligence

When building a report in Business Intelligence Studio 2008, I've noticed that the hide/show details indicators default to a plus sign [+] if the row(s) are set to display when the report is initially run. Then, clicking the control causes it to change to a minus sign [-] when the rows are hidden. This is backwards from what I would expect, and backwards from the way it works when the detail rows are initially hidden. In other words, the control always starts as a [+] regardless if the detail rows are initially visible or hidden. Have others stumbled across this issue or is it just me? Does anyone know of a fix or work around?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the InitialToggleState property in the Properties window, for the report item with the toggle (ie. the [+] or [-] sign).